# Change website line heights to unitless instead of pixels

Tags: feature-request, fonts

When my browser's minimum font size is set to 17px, the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ looks like this:

[image: screenshot 1]

If you change the CSS so that it uses `line-height: 1.2;` instead of `line-height: 12px;`, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot 2]

Just for completeness: Never having `line-height` in `px` is good; `line-height` in `px` is bad.  Can this be fixed?

Comment: You're correct px isn't the right unit for line-height. I'll be changing all the occurrences in our sites' css. (it may take a while)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have put in a fix for the global inbox line-height, it will be in the next production build. I'll be updating other px occurrences for line-height in our css.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks. Faster and simpler than I'd thought.